# Is it possible to disable encoding of query strings when forwarding request by Yarp?

Tags: c#, http, query-string, ms-yarp

I have following scenario, I am sending GET request to Yarp in order to be forwarded: `http://localhost:5123/api/sample-controller/v0/sample?filter=smth\.smth`. Currently I am using Kong as an reverse proxy and it is not encoding `\` character in query string so when this request is received in my asp net core application `HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value` is equal to `filter=smth\.smth`. I want to change reverse proxy for Yarp, however I have encountered problem. Since Yarp is encoding `\` (see screen below), in my code `HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value` is equal to `filter=smth%5C.smth`. I am specifically interested in `QueryString` because of backwards combability of my application custom binders. I know that standard `QueryStringValueProvider` is able to decode this character.

So the question is if it is possible to disable query string encoding on Yarp side? I would like to make it behave just like Kong in order to avoid changing legacy part of my application.

[Yarp encoding backslash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxQ52.png)

I have tried to search for such option in Yarp documentation and source code but without success.